# Skipping DNS and using IP adress in web dev as opposed to URLs

Tags: url, dns, domain-name

How much time would be saved in skipping the request for the IP of a domain name? Would it be noticeable. Before anyone gets to excited i know there could be problems with using an IP as opposed to a URL in web dev like if you have multiple servers, but im just curious.

Comment: By "web dev", do you mean web pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only thing it will do for you is insulate you from DNS failure. When your user experiences DNS problems, your site will be one the few that mysteriously keeps working for them!

You can still run multiple servers and load balance them behind a single IP, so that needn't be a worry. Generally though, there are far less pros than cons to this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they have to use the domain name to get to your site in the first place, their PC will cache the name and address, so anything you do after that won't make much difference.  It's not like it does a lookup over the net for every click.

Answer (score 2):

DNS resolution is cached at multiple levels. You would just be saving yourself a single roundtrip per session. Considering the hassles involved (IPs change more often than we'd like, and often not when we have control over them), I would seriously advice against it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the ip and hostname to you local hosts file if you want to be save from DNS failure and slow lookups.

Although I don't think there is much merit in it, since it kind of defeats the purpose of having dns :)